# Which is faster: Increment or equation with addition arithmetic

Tags: c, performance, math, increment, addition

Example:

```
a : ++i;
b : i++;
c : i += 1;
d : i = i + 1;
```

Assuming each of them abcd are called completely simultaneous, which one of them will be performed first ?

Comment: again could not find identical question (using the S/O searcher) so please if it is a duplicate don't downvote.. I'll just delete it and make everyone's life easier.

Comment: I would expect all of them to be exactly equivalent, but I'm not a c person.  But why do you care to begin with?  If you're good enough to have a program where this truly matters, then you're good enough to look through the generated byte code to figure out what's happening.

Comment: This is like telling me that everyone can find the every answer to his question.. as long as he ask. And this is kind of what I am doing right now.

Comment: what @Teepeemm means is that this point is the real bottleneck of your application, that means that your program is almost perfect. To reach that point, you have to be a very skilled dev => you can measure the answer in a test program faster than asking here.

Comment: How do you know this? What if I am working on a highly restricted interpreted environment ? (And yes that's true). I was never good in measuring.. in fact I never tried. I am not sure I even know how to do it accurately.

Comment: @Malina: "What if I am working on a highly restricted ..." Then the question cannot be answered here, as we neither have that environment, nor know how the interpreter works. Whereas for an interpreter, things are likely much different.

Comment: Even for a compiler, things are too complicated: if a previous opeartion requires to load `i` laready, the compiler might use different code than if it is not accessed. All that also depends on the CPU/instruction set or even instruction sequence, e.g. write-buffers. And much more. => the question is far too broad.

Comment: Well as I asked, I am mostly concerned if there is a attested difference at all. So two of the answers, answer the question.

Comment: If you are really interested in all this, read the instructon set manual of modern CPUs. As x86 is one of the most complicated architectures, you better start with something smaller but non-tivial, like ARM Cortex-M3/4. These are freely available for download (start with the Technical Reference Manual), instruction timing. Then read about compiler optimization techniques (just search for it).

Comment: If the compile statement does not have an optimization parameter or sets optimization off, then '++i' will be fastest.  however with optimization ON, each of the statements should produce the same instruction sequence (typically a single instruction)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular example all four expressions have the exact same externally observable result so a competent compiler should generate the exact same code for them.

The compiler doesn't slavishly read the code and generate a few instructions for each statement, the compiler reasons about what the result of the code should be according to the standard and generates the code needed for a whole program to behave as required. Therefore asking performance questions about single statements is almost always meaningless. Let me show an example:

```
void foo(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) { unsigned int i = a * b; }
void bar(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) { unsigned int i = a + b; }
```

Which one is faster? Function `foo` or `bar`? Many would say "of course multiplication is slower", but most likely the answer is: both are equally fast because a very simple dead store optimization will see that nothing uses `i`, so there's no need to compute it, so the compiler can optimize the functions down to nothing. Let's try it:

```
$ cat > foo.c
void foo(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) { unsigned int i = a * b; }
void bar(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) { unsigned int i = a + b; }
$ cc -S -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 foo.c
$ cat foo.s
[... I edited out irrelevant spam to make this more readable ...]
_foo:                                   ## @foo
    retq

_bar:                                   ## @bar
    retq
```

The only instruction in both functions is `retq` which just returns from the function.

Comment: If this answer is completely relevant, then it must be put as a description of the `[performance]` tag. And such questions will be only meaningless for those with problematic eyes.

Comment: This seems terrible to me. I mean, you just do garbage in a void function, the compile with optimizations. This doesn't tell which one of the syntax is the faster one

Comment: @Thomas That's the whole point. From the point of view of the compiler all the statements have the exact same observable behavior. My example was just to show that this is what a competent compiler will consider. The observable behavior of my example was nothing so the compiler generated the optimal code to achieve the observable behavior - no code at all.

Comment: @Thomas: the meaningful question would be "how many clock cycles does a particular CPU instruction take". Even the latter is not easy to answer due to the complex OoO nature of modern CPUs. Stating that any of the statements is "faster" is purely misleading.

Comment: What you're saying is that dead code take the same number of instruction than another dead code. I mean, change your function to a `printf("%d", a * b)` and `printf("%d", a + b)` and you'll see the real instructions: a `MUL` and an `ADD` then just look on google how many ticks are necessary to make a MUL and an ADD and you'll get a totally different number

Comment: @Thomas: The point is that two different operations with the same end result will likely have the same code generated for both.  All of `i++;`, `++i;`, `i += 1;`, and `i = i + 1;` have the same result (add 1 to `i`), so the compiler will most likely generate the same `INC` instruction for all four.  Similarly, both `foo` and `bar` have the same end result (they compute a value that isn't used anywhere, making them both effectively no-ops), so the compiler generates the same (no-op) code for both.

Answer (score 9):

Using gcc 5.2 to compile this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    ++i;
    i++;
    i += 1;
    i = i + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

It gives this ASM:

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
    add DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1 #++i
    add DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1 #i++
    add DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1 #i += 1
    add DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1 #i = i + 1
    mov eax, 0
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Which means that **with gcc 5.2** it's the exact same speed of execution.

---

It's seems to be the very same for version from 4.4.7 to 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

Modern compilers are smart enough to optimize all of the four cases to improve the performance.

You should note that in the last expression `i = i+1`, `i` will be evaluated twice.

Comment: Then abc will be performed first?

Comment: It depends upon how compiler optimize the last expression.

Comment: If it is EiC C89 or let's just say really old compiler.

Comment: What he means is that if you compile with optimization flags, most compilers should be able to layout the same machine code in all four cases. Of the four, `d` is the most likely candidate to not being fully optimized.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: Not necessarily. The compiler might combine with preceeding or succeeding operations, increment in-place or load/use/increment/store (for post-increment) depending on that. It might even take pipeline-stalls and write-buffering/dispersing into account. And much more.

Answer (score 0):

In Programming, Unary operators are having higher priority than the other operators. Unary Operators are executed before the execution of the other operators. Pre and Post Increment operators are the examples of the Unary operators while c and d are binary operators, hence executed later.Also c is just the short-hand notation for d, hence both take the same time and from a and b, a is executed earlier than b as post increment is faster than pre increment.
I hope this answer helps.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but operator precedence/priority determines which operation happens first *when there are multiple operations present*.  When there's only one operation, priority is meaningless, since that operation happens first.